# VSSonarExtension Downgrade

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sonarqube, visual-studio-extensions

I am using Visual Studio 2013, and recently updated VSSonarExtension (released on Jan 21st, 2016). This newer version (5.0.1) of VSSonarExtension is not working well, and it requires me to purchase license when I do preview analysis

```
http://www.jmecsoftware.com: License not found, or expired. 
Max 15 files can be analyzed per session.
```

The previous version (4.1.3) was working fine, and it allowed me to do incremental analysis and preview analysis with no error message.

What I can do for now is either fix this error message without license purchase or downgrade to 4.1.3. Could you guys please help me out?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Hey there, good question, I am experiencing the same error, plus a couple more. I asked this and a few other questions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950922/vssonarextention-why-connect-to-the-server) and wanted to offer you an opportunity to track this question in case someone answers it before yours as well as ask you if you have some answers to the other questions I asked. Hope it gets resolved for you

Answer (score 0):

the local file analysis is provided by external plugin, please contact support for the plugin. There are some opensource licenses if you need