# VSSonarExtention - why connect to the server?

Tags: visual-studio, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

Just installed and started using VSSonarExtension, but already have a couple of questions that I am unable to answer myself:

- Why does the extension need to connect to the server if it scans local code with local tools, such as FxCop and StyleCop?
- After looking through roughly 15 files, I get an error saying that I need a license to scan more than 15 files in one session - isn't the extension open source?
- I want to make sure that the rules specified on the server match the rules locally, so that I get the same output with regards to technical debt - how can I achieve it?
- Seems like the extension does not use FxCop, according to the logs; moreover, sometimes logs indicate that some code has been skipped because some rules were not present or defined in StyleCop. What does that mean?

Looking forward to your replies, thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answers

- so it can sync the quality profile in server, you dont want your users to complain the local analysis is different from what they have in server
- local files analysis, is provided by external plugin: please contact support their for details
- its the default behaviour. therefore ansering question 1
- please open a ticket in github with those issues. it can be that you have some differences between server profile and what is installed locally.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Overall, we could not overcome the challenges described in your answers, and opted for the command-line incremental analysis provided by Sonar folks themselves. That worked for us. Thanks!